# PHP Header Location Appends # to the URL

Tags: php

I couldn't find anything on the web about this, and this is not a major issue but it bothers me. Whenever I use php header function, it appends a # to the destination URL.

```php
<?php
include ("../utilities/core.php");

if(LoggedIn())
{
    header('Location: ../index.php');
    exit();
}
?>
```

It redirects to "localhost/index.php#" instead of "localhost/index.php". Is this the standard? If so what can I do to prevent it? If not what might be the cause of this and the solution?

Comment: Nothing in your code suggests that the hash part would be added. Have you looked into your JavaScript?

Comment: @Dharman I tried to disable all js files on index.php. The same result. I am using WAMP server by the way but I don't think it is the cause.

Comment: This doesn't look like a php  issue to me. More likely, your http server is appending this hash tag. Check your .htaccess file or virtual hosts configuration file to see if that's the culprit.